# Wordpress theme mods api and update

Tags: php, wordpress

After installing an update, my theme's mods are missing, and

```
get_theme_mod(..)
```

returns

```
NULL
```

the `wp_options` stores a bunch of theme mods called `theme_mods_XXX_YYY`, where `XXX` is the name of the theme and `YYY` is a random sequence of digits and letters 6 characters long

How can i save my old theme_mods ?